# How test (using NgXs) that an action was dispatched after dispatching another action, using ofActionSuccessful?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux, ngxs

Component logic

```
this.actions$
    .pipe(
       ofActionSuccessful(ProjectLoad),
       switchMap(() => interval(10000))
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.store.dispatch(new ProjecRefresh));
```

I'd like to test that **ProjecRefresh** is dispatched after dispatching **ProjectLoad** and I don't have any idea of how to do it

Comment: Couldn't you add console.log next to the actions you're trying to test?

Comment: what would be the purpose of doing that?

Comment: The logs would probably show you the order that each event is being called. Otherwise, if you want to do proper testing, please try something before asking for full solutions here. This is not a free coding provider.

Comment: my question is more about ofActionSuccessful, so I don't know how to mock up ofActionSuccessful, or make it to work in unit test

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51649402/15036361

Comment: @LeonardoFreirenot really, it was more how to mock actions$ and make ofActionSuccessful to get triggered

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that dispatching `ProjectLoad` should be a part of the state logic instead of a component: potential multiple consumers and complex refresh logic may force this sooner.

Then the component code transforms into something like

```ts
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new ProjectAutoRefreshEnabled())
}

...

ngOnDestroy() {
    // state logic may actually track consumers when this is handled
    // and decide to keep refreshing for other purposes
    // so this is something that shouldn't be in a component IMHO
    this.store.dispatch(new ProjectAutoRefreshDisabled())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I didn't how to refactor the code though...